# Get elements by tag from inside an element using Selenium Webdriver in Jmeter

Tags: selenium-webdriver, jmeter, jmeter-5.0

I want to retrieve all the  elements, in a another  element which I have fetched By.id.

```
var pieCharts = WDS.browser.findElement(pkg.By.id("queueStatsGraphs"));
```

Now, i want to retrieve all the div elements inside pieCharts. This is the html code:

```
<div class="row" id="queueStatsGraphs">
     <div class="col-md-6">Some Info</div>
     <div class="col-md-6">Some Another Info</div>
     <div class="col-md-6">Some Info</div>
     <div class="col-md-6">Some Another Info</div>
</div>
```

Now I want to retrieve all these div(s)inside the div with id 'queueStatsGraphs'.
How could i do that? Could anyone please me with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `pieCharts` is an instance of a [WebElement](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebElement.html) which in its turn provides [findElements()](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebElement.html#findElements-org.openqa.selenium.By-) function so you can access these inner "divs" like:

```
var children = pieCharts.findElements(org.openqa.selenium.By.className("col-md-6"))
```

Some example code:

```
WDS.sampleResult.sampleStart()
WDS.browser.get('/path/to/your/page')
var pieCharts = WDS.browser.findElement(org.openqa.selenium.By.id("queueStatsGraphs"))
var children = pieCharts.findElements(org.openqa.selenium.By.className("col-md-6"))
children.forEach(myFunction);
function myFunction(child) {
  WDS.log.info(child.getText());
}
WDS.sampleResult.sampleEnd()
```

Demo:

[image]

More information: [The WebDriver Sampler: Your Top 10 Questions Answered](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/webdriver-sampler-your-top-ten-questions-answered)

Comment: Thanks a lot, that worked! I tried using the same earlier, but instead of findElement, I was using findElements and that threw me an error. But thank you very much for your help!!